# Inferring exponential decay from difference equations?

Tags: recurrence-relations, exponential-function

I'm trying to justify, why the graph of the following system:

$$\begin{aligned} v(n) = 0.6 \cdot v(n-1) \\ p(n) = 0.13 \cdot v(n) + 0.87 \cdot p(n-1) + 25 \end{aligned}$$

with initial values $v(0) \approx 1441.67$, $p(0) = 3000$ and $p(1) = 3500$,
seems to show exponential decay for both $v(n)$ and $p(n)$ (after some initial growth).

Justifying this for $v(n)$ is easy:

$$v(n)=0.6^nv(0) \implies v(n) \text{ decays exponentially}$$

but what about $p(n)$?

I can write for example $p(3)$:

$$\begin{aligned}p(3)=a*b^3*v(0)+c*\bigg[a*b^2*v(0)+c*[a*b*v(0)+c*p(0)+25]\bigg]\\=a*b^3*v(0)+c*\bigg[a*b^2*v(0)+c*a*b*v(0)+c^2*p(0)+c*25\bigg]
\\=a*b^3*v(0)+c*a*b^2*v(0)+c^2*a*b^2*v(0)+c^3*p(0)+c^2*25\end{aligned}$$

where $a = 13/100,
b = 60/100, c = 87/100$
and one can see exponential *terms*, but the whole expression is too complicated in order to infer whether the decaying is "clean" exponential decay or whether it would exhibit some sort of other more complex curves.

Comment: Actually $p(n)$ cannot exhibit "exponential decay" since $$p(n)\to p_\infty=\frac{25}{1-0.87}\ne0$$ To study $(p(n))$, consider $$x(n)=\frac{p(n)-p_\infty}{0.87^n}$$ show that $$x(n)=x(n-1)+y(n)$$ for some explicit $y(n)$, and conclude.

Comment: I think that it is much more complex than an exponential decay. More than likely, $p_n=\alpha +\beta x^{-n}+\gamma y^{-n}$ with $x<1$ and $y<1$.

Comment: Adding graphs is allright, but are you going to apply the specific suggestions made in my previous comment or are you waiting for the algebra of a full solution to pop up on the page?

Comment: Oh yeah? So you stay silent about it rather than enquiring about whatever it is you do not understand in it? Would this mean that indeed you are "waiting for the algebra of a full solution to pop up on the page"? Anyway, what is it you "do not understand" in my comment? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did What is the relation $x(n) = \frac{p(n) - p_{\infty}}{0.87^n}$ and why study it? What can be concluded from $x(n)=x(n-1)+y(n)$?

Comment: "Why study it?" Because I tell you it will lead to a full solution. Is this a big no-no for you to perform any mathematical step suggested to you? What can be concluded from $x(n)=x(n-1)+y(n)$, you ask? Dunno, perhaps that $x(n)=x(0)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^ny(k)$, who knows? But once again, if you do not check yourself, yes you will stay stucked...

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed, but these are $x^n$ and $y^n$ (not $x^{-n}$ and $y^{-n}$), with $x=0.87$ and $y=x\cdot0.6$, and only the $x^n$ terms are visible in the simulations.

Comment: @Did What you mean only $x^n$ terms are visible? The plots are $v(n)$ and $p(n)$.

Comment: OK, my suggestion is to concentrate your efforts on writing a mathematical proof, understanding peripheral remarks (not addressed at you) would come later. I note that you still did not write a single line of a mathematical proof...

Comment: The plot for $p_n$ does not seem to be correct since $p_0=3000$, $p_1=3500$ (these are given as inital conditions in the question), $p_2=3589$, $p_3\approx 3459$,  $p_4\approx 3221$, $p_5\approx 2939$.

Comment: Peripheral again, and yet... If $v(0) \approx 1441.67$ and $p(0) = 3000$ then $p(1)\approx2747$, not $p(1)= 3500$.

Comment: @Did. This is given in the post and in the previous question. I must confess that I don't anything anymore with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use *z*-transform as
$$V(z)=0.6z^{-1}V(z)+v(0)\\P(z)=0.13V(z)+0.87z^{-1}P(z)+p(0)+25$$
to get a linear set of equations. Solving this linear equation yields:
$$\begin{align}
V(z)&=\frac{v(0)}{1-0.6z^{-1}}\\
P(z)&=\frac{p(0)+25}{1-0.87z^{-1}}+\frac{0.13v(0)}{(1-0.87z^{-1})(1-0.6z^{-1})}
\end{align}$$
Now use the inverse *z*-transform to get:
$$\begin{align}
v(n)&=0.6^n\,v(0)\\
p(n)&=0.87^n\,\left(25+ p(0)\right)+v(0)\left(0.419\times 0.87^n-0.289\times 0.6^n\right)
\end{align}$$

**Addendum:**

You can also use a discrete-time dynamical system model for this set of equations to better understand its behavior. Here I would define:
$$x_n=\pmatrix{v(n)\\p(n)}$$
and obtain a model in the form of $x_n=Ax_{n-1}+Bu_n$, where:
$$A=\pmatrix{0&0.6\\0.078&0.87},\qquad B=\pmatrix{0\\25}$$
now it is sufficient to find the (unit)step-response of this system.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this shows exponential decay? I'm not that familiar with the $z$-transform in such sums and products equation setting.

Comment: @mavavilj As I told you